# python-poppler-qt5 installation error on mac

Tags: python, pyqt5, poppler

I am trying to install the package [python_poppler-qt5](https://pypi.org/project/python-poppler-qt5/), but I've got the following error:

```
pip install python-poppler-qt5

Collecting python-poppler-qt5
  Using cached python-poppler-qt5-21.1.0.tar.gz (28 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/xizg0003/opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/xizg0003/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/57/f7xzdhs15v50pw097zyr8c44mxrzqx/T/tmp13hlg21d
         cwd: /private/var/folders/57/f7xzdhs15v50pw097zyr8c44mxrzqx/T/pip-install-5gvnukb2/python-poppler-qt5
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
    /usr/local/opt/qt/bin/qmake -query
    These bindings will be built: Poppler-Qt5.
    Generating the Poppler-Qt5 bindings...
    _in_process.py: /private/var/folders/57/f7xzdhs15v50pw097zyr8c44mxrzqx/T/pip-build-env-fkuu2mr4/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/bindings/QtCore/QtCore.toml: 'QtCore' was built against ABI v12 but this module is being built against ABI v13
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/xizg0003/opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/xizg0003/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/57/f7xzdhs15v50pw097zyr8c44mxrzqx/T/tmp13hlg21d Check the logs for full command output.
```

So it seems to be a version conflict. Could you help me figure out how to solve this issue?

Installation environment

- macOS Catalina v 10.15.4
- python         v  3.7.6
- PyQt5          v  5.15.4

After having unistalled Qt6 and installed Qt5 via homebrew I got the following error:

```
pip install python-poppler-qt5

Collecting python-poppler-qt5
  Using cached python-poppler-qt5-21.1.0.tar.gz (28 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/xizg0003/opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/xizg0003/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/57/f7xzdhs15v50pw097zyr8c44mxrzqx/T/tmpnu302c2v
         cwd: /private/var/folders/57/f7xzdhs15v50pw097zyr8c44mxrzqx/T/pip-install-_wyb5s0h/python-poppler-qt5
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
    /Users/xizg0003/opt/anaconda3/bin/qmake -query
    These bindings will be built: Poppler-Qt5.
    Generating the Poppler-Qt5 bindings...
    _in_process.py: poppler-form.sip:152: ::Poppler::FormFieldChoice::choicesWithExportValues() unsupported function return type - provide %MethodCode and a C++ signature
    
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/xizg0003/opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/xizg0003/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/57/f7xzdhs15v50pw097zyr8c44mxrzqx/T/tmpnu302c2v Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: What version of Qt do you have installed: `/usr/local/opt/qt/bin/qmake -query`?

Comment: QT_VERSION:6.0.3

Comment: That's the problem, PyQt5 uses Qt5, not Qt6. My recommendation is that you uninstall Qt6 and install Qt 5.15.4

Comment: I unistalled Qt6 and installed Qt5 via brew, but now I got another error:
    "Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
    /Users/xizg0003/opt/anaconda3/bin/qmake -query
    These bindings will be built: Poppler-Qt5.
    Generating the Poppler-Qt5 bindings...
    _in_process.py: poppler-form.sip:152: ::Poppler::FormFieldChoice::choicesWithExportValues() unsupported function return type - provide %MethodCode and a C++ signature"

Comment: Checking the repo I see that there is a bug, can you run the sip-build command in console?

Comment: I can't: "sip-build: pyproject.toml: there is no such file in the current directory". I have the feeling I messed around with packages installations

Comment: Okay, I just want to check that you have the tools, you can run git command

Comment: I can, that works properly

Comment: wait for me a moment so I can post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error is caused by using a different version with which PyQt5 was compiled, in this case Qt6 was used but PyQt5 was compiled with Qt 5.15.4.

The second error is caused because the code uploaded to pypi has a bug, in this case the solution is to use the code from the project repository and compile it directly:

```
pip install PyQt-builder sip
git clone https://github.com/frescobaldi/python-poppler-qt5
cd python-poppler-qt5
sip-build
sip-install
```

Comment: this worked (after having installed the builder with pip install PyQt-builder, in my case). Many thanks!